# Enable wifi antenna in boot-repair environment

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, antenna, bootrepair

L.S.,

I'm trying to fix things with Boot-repair(bootable disk) but it needs internet to work properly.
The thing is, my wifi antenna auto-enables when i boot windows and linux, but this is not the case when i boot into Boot-repair. And i can't enable it with it's hotkey, (fn+) f12.
It just stays disabled, and i can't find any or option button to enable it in Boot-repair.
Maybe there is a command to enable it?
Can someone help me?
Or is it perfectly reasonable to use Boot-repair without internet connection?
That would seem strange to me as Boot-reapir itself strictly says it needs it.
Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: I have successfully used a live boot installation CD, which has a lot of repair tools built in, and it recognises most wireless interfaces. If you boot in _Run from CD_ mode, and it recognises your wireless card, then you can down-load any other repair tools you need (albeit into memory, which will be lost on a reboot, necessitating a repeated down-load).

Answer (score 0):

If your 'boot repair' is linux based, it's very well possible that the wireless card isn't recognized due to the absence of correct firmware.

Please provide us with more information on the repair disk: it is a read only disk, or could you be able to install extra drivers while running the repair disk? If so: try to find out which type your wireless card is, with the `lspci` or `lsusb` commands. There's a good chance that the information from these commands will help you find the correct drivers, should they be missing.

Comment: It's a bootable usb so i could add more drivers etc. I have a Realtek RTL8188EE Adapter. What's the best way to install a driver for this on the usb?